# nvarchar and nclob with db2 9.7

Tags: db2, nvarchar

The db2 9.7 sql reference clearly states that `nvarchar` and `nclob` datatypes are synonyms of `vargraphic` and `dbclob`, respectively (link [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0057004.html))

Yet, when I write a simple create table statement, it doesn't work with `nvarchar` and `nclob` - I get an error message about unknown tokens. When using `vargraphic` and `dbclob` as is well.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documents](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0054110.html), NVARCHAR and NCLOB were introduced in DB2 9.7 with Fixpack 2.

I presume you're running either the GA release or Fixpack 1.